# .ics calendar time 1 hour out in Apple Calendar and has no time in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am coding the generation of an .ics file in PHP.

The .ics file generates fine and can be imported into Apple and Google Calendars.

However I have the following issue with the events I have included, an example event in the generated file is:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1952849664
DTSTAMP:20230426T084708Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230606T103000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230606T103000
SUMMARY:Test Event
DESCRIPTION:Test event 
multi line description test
multi line description test
END:VEVENT
```

This event appears in both calendars however:

1. In Apple Calendar the event is 1 hour ahead, I am expecting the event to be at 10:30 and it is shown at 11:30
2. In Google Calendar the event has no time at all

What do I need to change in my event to fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

I reference the [iCalendar Standard Page (RFC5545)](https://icalendar.org/RFC-Specifications/iCalendar-RFC-5545/) using the section numbers below so you can see it documented for yourself.

An iCS file will function as intended when it starts with `BEGIN:VCALENDAR` and ends with `END:VCALENDAR` [(See example in 3.4. iCalendar Object)](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-4-icalendar-object.html).
In my experience, some programs and apps will fail to read the iCS file at all if this is excluded, so **I would highly recommend adding this on a new line at the top and bottom** to encapsulate your current iCS contents.

As for fixing your time issues, these may stem from a mismatch between the format you tell `DTSTART` and `DTEND` it to expect and then the actual formatting you give it. For example, on the line that says `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230606T103000`, you specify that the value is `DATE` but give it a datetime with `20230606T103000`. **If you want to retain the time aspect, you should change `VALUE=DATE` to say `VALUE=DATE-TIME`** [(8.3.4 Value Data Types Registry)](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/8-3-4-value-data-types-registry.html), but if you completely remove `VALUE=DATE`, it will default to `VALUE=DATE-TIME` anyway
[(3.6.1. Event Component)](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-1-event-component.html).